# insert list as a new column mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have a list of string values `new_values` and I want to insert it as a new column in the `companies` tables my mysql database. Since I have hundreds of rows, I cannot manually type them using the ? syntax that I came across on SO.

```
import MySQLdb

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO companies ....")

lst_to_add = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]

db.commit()
db.close()
```

However, i am not sure what query I should use to pass in my list and what's the correct syntax to include the new **column name** (eg: "newCol") into the query.

Edit:
current table:

```
id     originalName     
1      Hannah           
2      Joi              
3      Kale
```

expected output:

```
id     originalName     fakeName
1      Hannah           name1
2      Joi              name2
3      Kale             name3
```

Comment: The column name is up to you, you know what this data is, you didnt tell us, so you are best placed to think up a meaning full name

Comment: If you are attempting to add this new data to Existing customer rows, you will be lookig for an UPDATE query and not a INSERT

Comment: My question is about how I will include the columnName in the query, like what'S the syntax. I am not asking for suggestions regarding the name @RiggsFolly In this question, I am looking for an insert/new column but would be great if you could enlighten me with the syntax of updating too

Comment: You dont insert just because the column is new, an INSERT creates a NEW ROW and UPDATE changes an Existing ROW

Comment: An example of the contents of the `lst_to_add` would be useful

Comment: probably something like  `cursor.execute(UPDATE companies SET new_column = %s", [new_value])`

Comment: If this is a new column in the table, you first need to use `ALTER TABLE` to add the column to the table, before you can update rows with the new values.

Comment: If you're updating rows in an existing table, you need to specify which row each name should be added to. `UPDATE companies SET newCol = ? WHERE otherCol = ?`

Comment: You can use a loop to process all the rows to update.

Comment: Can you help by writing an answer? @Barmar

Comment: I started to write an answer, then I realized that you didn't show which rows the values should be added to. That's why I posted my last comment.

Comment: Show what the table currently contains, and what you expect it to look like after the code runs.

Comment: I think this needs some clarity.  Adding a new column to a DB requires a schema change.  Has that been done?  Is your input data arranged to update the new column based on row ID?  You can use similar syntax to above, but, as mentioned, you need update, not insert.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ALTER TABLE` to add the new column.

```
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE companies ADD COLUMN fakeName VARCHAR(100)")
```

Then loop through the data, updating each row. You need Python data that indicates the mapping from original name to fake name. You can use a dictionary, for example.

```
names_to_add = {
    "Hannah": "name1",
    "Joi": "name2",
    "Kale": "name3"
}

for oldname, newname in names_to_add.items():
    cursor.execute("UPDATE companies SET fakeName = %s WHERE originalName = %s", (newname, oldname))
```

Comment: I think this should work.  BUT, based on OPs post, I don't see anything that suggests ORM.  If your schema isn't managed by your code, I would not try to change the schema in code.  Just my two cents.

Comment: I don't understand the reference to an ORM. I guess I should suggest that he add the column outside the script, but it's the same effect.